# Seek method behavior in spring kafka consumer 1.2.x

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I do not want to commit offsets for those messages for which processing fails and I want them to be re-delivered again for processing. I am using spring-kafka 1.2.x and implemented **ConsumerSeekAware** in my listener.

```
@Component
public class Listener implements ConsumerSeekAware {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Listener.class);

    private final ThreadLocal<ConsumerSeekCallback> seekCallBack = new ThreadLocal<>();

    @KafkaListener(topics = "my-topic", containerFactory = "kafkaManualAckListenerContainerFactory")
    public void listen1(ConsumerRecord<String, String> consumerRecord) throws MyCustomException {
        logger.info("received: key - " + consumerRecord.key() + " value - " + consumerRecord.value());

        // Below code is just to show the issue.Not acknowledging so I can get the same msg again.
        boolean should_commit = false;
        if(should_commit) {
            ack.acknowledge();
        }
        else {
            this.seekCallBack.get().seek(consumerRecord.topic(), consumerRecord.partition() , consumerRecord.offset());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void registerSeekCallback(ConsumerSeekCallback callback) {
        logger.info("registerSeekCallback called..");
        this.seekCallBack.set(callback);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPartitionsAssigned(Map<TopicPartition, Long> assignments, ConsumerSeekCallback callback) {
     logger.info("onPartitionsAssigned called..");
    }

    @Override
    public void onIdleContainer(Map<TopicPartition, Long> assignments, ConsumerSeekCallback callback) {
        logger.info("onIdleContainer called..");
    }
}
```

#########Contaianer config (auto.commit is false in consumer)

```
factory.getContainerProperties().setAckOnError(false);
          factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
```

The problem I am facing is if I have 10 messages in different partitions for a topic so I am getting all of them one by one and after getting all the messages I keep on getting the last message for any partition. I also tried **SeekToCurrentErrorHandler** which is implemented in version 2.0.x and that works perfectly. but I can not upgrade my kafka version. If I restart the container I get all the messages again which is fine but I don't want to stop the container when processing of a message fails.

So my question is it even possible to get the same (Exactly same without any need of stopping the container) behavior same as **SeekToCurrentErrorHandler** in spring-kafka 1.2.x ?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "keep on getting the last message". `>but I can not upgrade my kafka version.`
You don't have to; newer kafka-clients can talk to older brokers (as long as you don't use new features), thanks to KIP-35.

Comment: If I have msg on partition 10 on offset 47,48,49...53 (Last msg on 53) and I do not send ack for any of them then I get all the msgs from 47 to 53 and after that I keep on getting the same msg which is at 53 offset. What I want is if I do not send ack at offset 47 then I should get the same msg at offset 47 again n again and pointer should not move ahead.

Comment: You keep getting it because you keep seeking it. You have to drain (ignore) any remaining messages from the last poll until you see the failed message again. This is all done automatically with the `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler`, which can't be used with 1.x. So you have to simulate it's work in your listener.

Comment: So is it not possible by using "ConsumerSeekAware" that I can get next msg as the same one delivered to listener which failed. I tried using "max.poll.records"=1 but still getting multiple records. What I want is to take the msg from kafka and call external web-service and if that fails I want to retry the same msg continuously till it gets delivered.

Comment: `max.poll.records=1` would solve it if you upgrade to 1.3.x or later (before 1.3, one or more polls may have occurred on another thread. You could use [the built in retry mechanism instead](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/_reference.html#retrying-deliveries) and the same record will be sent to the listener each time until retries are exhausted (which might be never, with a suitably configured retry policy). But it's probably best to stop the container if you have an extended problem. But the best solution is to upgrade to 2.1.6.